# Ink smart contracts are giving build error when i am using ethabi rust crate

Tags: ink, ethereum

To encode and decode data the way we do in solidity I am using [ethabi](https://docs.rs/ethabi/latest/ethabi/). It is working fine in compilation and testing but when I am running the command `cargo contract build`, it is giving me a build error.

Let me know if someone can help me on this issue or has any other way.

Comment: Could you please provide more details regarding the problem? Some code snippet, build error logs, crate versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following changes in your contact **Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
ink = { version ="4.0.0-alpha.3", default-features = false }
ethabi = { path = "../ethabi", default-features = false } 
hex = { version = "0.4.3", default-features = false } 
scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.2.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }


[profile.release] 
overflow-checks = false
```

Earlier it was as following

```
[dependencies]
ink = { version ="4.0.0-alpha.3", default-features = false }
ethabi = { path = "../ethabi" }
hex = { version = "0.4.3" }

scale = { package = "parity-scale-codec", version = "3.2.1", default-features = false, features = ["derive"] }
scale-info = { version = "2", default-features = false, features = ["derive"], optional = true }
```

Comment: You said the following **changes** but never posted the original `Cargo.toml`. Changes from what?

Comment: Sounds like the answer is "remember to add `default-features = false` when importing `ethabi` and `hex`".